# arraylist.isEmpty works only in a loop and not outside

Tags: java, loops

In this class I store a number and content belonging to this number. In the method `deleteContentIfOlderThen()` I check if the `ArrayList(opexContent)` is empty. But this works only if the check occurs inside the `for` loop. If I check it outside it doesn't work. I use a `workStealingExecutorService` to execute this method. But the list is only accessed by this class while the threads do the work.

So what am I doing wrong that it doesn't work outside the loop?

3. version with `list.removeIf()`

```
package org.excelAnalyser;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.function.Predicate;

public class OpexLine implements Runnable{
    public static final int DELETE_CONTENT_TASK=0;
    public final int SAPNumber;
    public final ArrayList<String[]> opexContent;
    
    private final DeletionRequestHandler m_deletionRequestHandler;
    private String[] m_taskParameters=null;
    private int m_taskid=-1;
    
    public OpexLine(int SAPNumber, ArrayList<String[]> opexContent, DeletionRequestHandler deletionRequestHandler) {
        this.SAPNumber=SAPNumber;
        this.opexContent=opexContent;
        m_deletionRequestHandler=deletionRequestHandler;
    }
    public void setupTask(int taskID, String[] parameters) {
        m_taskid=taskID;
        m_taskParameters=parameters;
    }
    public void run() {
        if(m_taskid<0) {
            System.out.println("aborted task because no taskID was given");
            return;
        }
        if(m_taskParameters==null) {
            System.out.println("no taskparameters were specified");
            return;
        }
        switch (m_taskid) {
        case DELETE_CONTENT_TASK:
            deleteContentIfOlderThen();
            break;
        }
    }
    private void deleteContentIfOlderThen() {
        final long unixTime=Long.parseLong(m_taskParameters[0]);
        final int indexOfTime=Integer.parseInt(m_taskParameters[1]);
        final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
        final Date checkDate=new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()-unixTime);
        opexContent.removeIf(new Predicate<String[]>() {
            public boolean test(String[] content) {
                final String timeString=content[indexOfTime];
                if(timeString==null || timeString.isEmpty()) {
                    return false;
                }
                Date date = null;
                try {
                    date = sdf.parse(timeString);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return false;
                    //date = new Date();
                }
                return date.before(checkDate);
            }
        });
        if(opexContent.isEmpty()) {
            m_deletionRequestHandler.requestDeletionFor(this);
        }
    }
    public String toString() {
        final StringBuilder stringBuilder=new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append(SAPNumber);
        stringBuilder.append(": ");
        final int length=String.valueOf(SAPNumber).length();
        //gen offset
        final StringBuilder offsetBuilder=new StringBuilder();
        for(int i=0; i<length+2; i++) {
            offsetBuilder.append(' ');
        }
        final String offset=offsetBuilder.toString();
        for (String[] strings : opexContent) {
            
            for (String string : strings) {
                stringBuilder.append(string+"; ");
            }
            stringBuilder.append("\n"+offset);
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
}
```

2. version with iterator:

```
package org.excelAnalyser;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class OpexLine implements Runnable{
    public static final int DELETE_CONTENT_TASK=0;
    public final int SAPNumber;
    public final ArrayList<String[]> opexContent;
    
    private final DeletionRequestHandler m_deletionRequestHandler;
    private String[] m_taskParameters=null;
    private int m_taskid=-1;
    
    public OpexLine(int SAPNumber, ArrayList<String[]> opexContent, DeletionRequestHandler deletionRequestHandler) {
        this.SAPNumber=SAPNumber;
        this.opexContent=opexContent;
        m_deletionRequestHandler=deletionRequestHandler;
    }
    public void setupTask(int taskID, String[] parameters) {
        m_taskid=taskID;
        m_taskParameters=parameters;
    }
    public void run() {
        if(m_taskid<0) {
            System.out.println("aborted task because no taskID was given");
            return;
        }
        if(m_taskParameters==null) {
            System.out.println("no taskparameters were specified");
            return;
        }
        switch (m_taskid) {
        case DELETE_CONTENT_TASK:
            deleteContentIfOlderThen();
            break;
        }
    }
    private void deleteContentIfOlderThen() {
        final long unixTime=Long.parseLong(m_taskParameters[0]);
        final int indexOfTime=Integer.parseInt(m_taskParameters[1]);
        final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
        Iterator<String[]> opexContentIterator=opexContent.iterator();
        contentLoop: while(opexContentIterator.hasNext()) {
            
            String[] content=(String[])opexContentIterator.next();
            
            final String timeString=content[indexOfTime];
            if(timeString==null || timeString.isEmpty()) {
                continue contentLoop;
            }
            Date date = null;
            try {
                date = sdf.parse(timeString);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                continue contentLoop;
                //date = new Date();
            }
            Date checkDate=new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()-unixTime);
            if(date.before(checkDate)) {
                opexContentIterator.remove();
            }
        }
        if(opexContent.isEmpty()) {
            m_deletionRequestHandler.requestDeletionFor(this);
        }
    }
    public String toString() {
        final StringBuilder stringBuilder=new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append(SAPNumber);
        stringBuilder.append(": ");
        final int length=String.valueOf(SAPNumber).length();
        //gen offset
        final StringBuilder offsetBuilder=new StringBuilder();
        for(int i=0; i<length+2; i++) {
            offsetBuilder.append(' ');
        }
        final String offset=offsetBuilder.toString();
        for (String[] strings : opexContent) {
            
            for (String string : strings) {
                stringBuilder.append(string+"; ");
            }
            stringBuilder.append("\n"+offset);
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
}
```

1. version without iterator:

```java
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

public class OpexLine implements Runnable{
    public static final int DELETE_CONTENT_TASK=0;
    public final int SAPNumber;
    public final ArrayList<String[]> opexContent;
    
    private final DeletionRequestHandler m_deletionRequestHandler;
    private String[] m_taskParameters=null;
    private int m_taskid=-1;
    
    public OpexLine(int SAPNumber, ArrayList<String[]> opexContent, DeletionRequestHandler deletionRequestHandler) {
        this.SAPNumber=SAPNumber;
        this.opexContent=opexContent;
        m_deletionRequestHandler=deletionRequestHandler;
    }
    public void setupTask(int taskID, String[] parameters) {
        m_taskid=taskID;
        m_taskParameters=parameters;
    }
    public void run() {
        if(m_taskid<0) {
            System.out.println("aborted task because no taskID was given");
            return;
        }
        if(m_taskParameters==null) {
            System.out.println("no taskparameters were specified");
            return;
        }
        switch (m_taskid) {
        case DELETE_CONTENT_TASK:
            deleteContentIfOlderThen();
            break;
        }
    }
    private void deleteContentIfOlderThen() {
        final long unixTime=Long.parseLong(m_taskParameters[0]);
        final int indexOfTime=Integer.parseInt(m_taskParameters[1]);
        final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
        
        contentLoop: for(final String[] content : opexContent) {
            //final String[] content=opexContent.get(i);
            final String timeString=content[indexOfTime];
            if(timeString==null || timeString.isEmpty()) {
                continue contentLoop;
            }
            Date date = null;
            try {
                date = sdf.parse(timeString);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                continue contentLoop;
                //date = new Date();
            }
            Date checkDate=new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()-unixTime);
            //System.out.println(date+" before "+checkDate+": "+date.before(checkDate));
            if(date.before(checkDate)) {
                System.out.println("removed");
                opexContent.remove(content);
                if(opexContent.isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.println("isEmptyAfterRemoval");
                    m_deletionRequestHandler.requestDeletionFor(this);
                }
            }
        }
        //System.out.println("isexecuted");
        if(opexContent.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("isEmpty");
            m_deletionRequestHandler.requestDeletionFor(this);
        }
    }
    public String toString() {
        final StringBuilder stringBuilder=new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append(SAPNumber);
        stringBuilder.append(": ");
        final int length=String.valueOf(SAPNumber).length();
        //gen offset
        final StringBuilder offsetBuilder=new StringBuilder();
        for(int i=0; i<length+2; i++) {
            offsetBuilder.append(' ');
        }
        final String offset=offsetBuilder.toString();
        for (String[] strings : opexContent) {
            
            for (String string : strings) {
                stringBuilder.append(string+"; ");
            }
            stringBuilder.append("\n"+offset);
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "it doesn't work"? (BTW it is very *dangerous* to change the list while iterating over it, unless changes are made using its own iterator)

Comment: You should never mutate a list while you are iterating it. Calls to `opexContent#remove` should be replaced with a call to `Iterator#remove` (with the `Iterator` coming from `opexContent#iterator`). I'm honestly surprised you didn't get a `ConcurrentModificationException`, though you might've gotten one and the `ExecutorService` simply swallowed the error.

Comment: @Rogue Thank you for the advice. It seems to work. But would have been there other solution other then to use an Iterator?

Comment: You can determine the items which remain in a separate list, but for in-place removal, you will need to use an `Iterator`.

Comment: @Rogue Would you be so kind and add your comment as an answer which I could accept as solved?

Comment: By the way, the terrible `Date` class was years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Comment: Oh it isn't so terrible if you want a really thin rapper around the unixTime. Just saying. Just my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never mutate a list while you are iterating it. This type of code:

```
final ArrayList<String[]> opexContent;

private void deleteContentIfOlderThen() {
    for(final String[] content : opexContent) {
        Date date = /* some date */;
        Date checkDate=new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()-unixTime);
        if(date.before(checkDate)) {
            opexContent.remove(content); //CME!
        }
    }
}
```

Will likely cause a `ConcurrentModificationException`, as the list was mutated while an `Iterator` was in use (behind the scenes). Instead, you should use the `Iterator` directly, such that you have the ability to use `Iterator#remove`:

```
final ArrayList<String[]> opexContent;

private void deleteContentIfOlderThen() {
    Iterator<String[]> itr = opexContent.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        String[] content = itr.next();
        Date date = /* some date */;
        Date checkDate=new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()-unixTime);
        if(date.before(checkDate)) {
            itr.remove(); //No more CME!
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Whilst [Rogue's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73140051/3788176) is correct in saying that you shouldn't remove elements from the list while iterating it, there's a neater way of removing the elements since Java 8 that avoids using an iterator explicitly:

```
// Doesn't have to be moved outside, but at least doing this means
// you're comparing against a fixed check date, rather than potentially
// changing as you iterate.
Date checkDate=new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()-unixTime);

opexContent.removeIf(content -> {
  Date date = /* some date */;
  return date.before(checkDate);
});
```

This is better because

1. it's clearer, because you're not having to deal with the iterator
2. it's safer, as it leaves the list untouched if an exception is thrown for some element (i.e. it's failure atomic);
3. it's more efficient, because it avoids resizing the list repeatedly